# Pester Mock does not work for Invoke-Command using script block

Tags: unit-testing, powershell, dependency-injection, invoke-command, pester

I have a console logger

```
function Common-Write-Log-Console
{
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $logText
        )

        $textToOutput = [String]::Format("{0}:{1}", [System.DateTime]::Now.ToString(), $logText)
        Write-Output ($textToOutput)
}
```

Then I have wrapper function which calls it by dynamically loading it

```
function Common-Write-Log-WithInvoke
{
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $logText

        )

    foreach($logger in $loggers.Values)
    {
        Invoke-Command $logger -ArgumentList $logText,$verbosityLevel,$logType
    }

}
```

Another wrapper function which calls it directly

```
function Common-Write-Log-WithoutInvoke
{
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string] $logText, 
        [string] $verbosityLevel = "Normal",
        [string] $logType = "Info"
        )

    Common-Write-Log-Console $logText

}
```

Add Loggers for dynamic calling

```
 $loggers = @{}
 $loggers.Add("Console_Logger", ${function:Common-Write-Log-Console})
```

Now I have couple of Pester tests

```
 # pester tests
Describe "Common-Write-Log" {
    It "Test 1. Calls all log sources when log sources are called directly - **this test passes**" {


        # Arrange
        $expectedLogText  = "test message" 
        Mock Common-Write-Log-Console -Verifiable -ParameterFilter { $logText -eq  $expectedLogText}

        # Act
        Common-Write-Log-WithoutInvoke "test message"

        # Assert
        Assert-VerifiableMocks
    }

    It "Test 2. Calls all log sources when log sources are called through Invoke-Command - **this test fails**" {


        # Arrange
        $expectedLogText  = "test message" 
        Mock Common-Write-Log-Console -Verifiable -ParameterFilter { $logText -eq  $expectedLogText}

        # Act
        Common-Write-Log-WithInvoke "test message"

        # Assert
        Assert-VerifiableMocks # This statement fails as actual function "Common-Write-Log-Console" is called instead of the mocked one
    }
}
```

Test 2. always fails. I have worked around by creating a fake logger function, instead of using mock and setting some global variables to verify/assert in my test that dynamic loading and calling of intended function works. It would be nice to get the Mock working in such scenario , rather then writing those dumb fakes!

Any ideas how would it work or is it not supported by pester at all?

PS: All code works if copied in order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Pester's Scope of Mocked Function Interception

Pester only intercepts calls to mocked functions in particular scopes.  I think the only supported method of controlling this scope is using [`InModuleScope`](https://github.com/pester/Pester/wiki/InModuleScope).  That allows you to designate that Pester should intercept calls to mocked functions in the module that you have specified using `InModuleScope`.

### `Common-Write-Log-Console` is Not Called in a Scope where Pester Intercepts

In "Test 2.", the "call" to `Common-Write-Log-Console` takes place somewhere inside this call:

```
Invoke-Command $logger -ArgumentList $logText,$verbosityLevel,$logType
```

You have not specified that Pester should intercept calls to mocked functions inside whatever module `Invoke-Command` is implemented.  (I doubt that you could achieve this, because `Invoke-Command` is shipped with WMF and probably not implemented in PowerShell.)

### Use the Call Operator Instead of Invoke-Command

When invoking PowerShell commands as delegates I recommend using the [`&` call operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx) instead of `Invoke-Command`.  If you rewrite this line

```
Invoke-Command $logger -ArgumentList $logText,$verbosityLevel,$logType
```

as

```
& $logger -logText $logText
```

Test 2, should call the mock for `Common-Write-Log-Console` as you desire.

### A Handle to a PowerShell Delegate is Just a String Containing the Function Name

When invoking a PowerShell delegate, all you need is a string containing the name of the function.  If you rewrite this line

```
$loggers.Add("Console_Logger", ${function:Common-Write-Log-Console})
```

as

```
$loggers.Add("Console_Logger", 'Common-Write-Log-Console')
```

`$logger` will correctly contain the name of the command which the call operator can invoke.

---

I tested this on my computer and both tests now pass:

[image]

Comment: alx9r, thanks for the answer, I totally understand why it's not working and exactly had in mind what you explained. I have tried the call operator with same failure. I also have tried calling function using the statement $logger.Invoke($logText, $verbosityLevel, $logType), but this also result in same failure.

Comment: @scorpio I just had a chance to run your code.  The culprit was `${function:Common-Write-Log-Console}`.  I updated my answer.  Both tests now pass on my machine.

Comment: Hi alx9r, many thanks for clarifying, it resolves my understanding of delegates in power shell. When debugging I was wondering why the whole function body was being copied in the $loggers["Console_Logger"] when using the old statement "$loggers.Add("Console_Logger", ${function:Common-Write-Log-Console})